# Send and receive iot-hub messages

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am working on a project based on the azure sphere kit where I want to control a motor from a web application. I managed to send the command to the iot hub and the build in monitor shows that the message is received by the iot hub. Now, my question is: How can I forward this message to the board? I have to mention that this is my first experience with the iot-hub so please dont judge me if it is a stupid question.:) [Here is the confirmation that the message is received by the iothub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQyPm.png)

Comment: You can use the ServiceClient class to send C2D messages in an Azure function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.serviceclient?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate with your Azure Sphere from Azure IoT Hub, you're talking about Cloud-to-device communication. There are three different ways to do this communication:

- Direct Methods
- Device Twin Desired Properties
- Cloud-to-device (C2D) messages

Microsoft documented them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). This document also lists the different considerations for each of the three methods.

To forward the IoT Hub message that you mentioned in your question, a good start would be to write an Azure Function that listens to the IoT Hub output and send that to the device using one of the three methods above. You can find an example for the Azure Function IoT Hub trigger [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more detailed options in this scenario to the above responses.

**Scenario 1:** You may be interested in *configuring* your devices from your back-end service(s) as your web application. To synchronize *state information* between a device and an IoT hub, you use [device twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins). A *desired* property is set by a back-end application and read by a device. A *reported* property is set by a device and read by a back-end application. A *tag* is set by a back-end application and is never sent to a device. You use tags to organize your devices. *Long-running commands intended to put the device into a certain desired state. For example, set the telemetry send interval to 30 minutes.* This completes your E2E state synchronization scenario : **Web-Application<=>IoT Device**, [Ref Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-device-twins)

[image]

**Question:** *How can I forward this message to the board?*

**Scenario 2**: You may be interested in *direct method* to control a device connected to your IoT hub. You can use direct methods to remotely change the *behavior* of devices connected to your IoT hub. Commands that require immediate confirmation, such as turning on a fan.

**Requirements:**

-->**IoT Device:** To receive the direct method calls, the applications running on IoT Device connect to a *device-specific endpoint* on your IoT hub.

```
HostName={YourIoTHubName}.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=MyNodeDevice;SharedAccessKey={YourSharedAccessKey}
```

-->**Web-Application:** To call a direct method on a device, your Web application connects to *service-side endpoint* on your IoT hub.

```
HostName={YourIoTHubName}.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=service;SharedAccessKey={YourSharedAccessKey}
```

Direct Method calls: Points to be noted. Please visit the link: [detailed comparison of the various cloud-to-device communication options.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance)

- The maximum direct method payload size is 128 KB.
- Disconnected devices are not contacted. The solution back end is notified that the device is not connected.
  [Ref Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp#retrieve-the-service-connection-string)

If you need further help in this matter, please comment in the below section and we will be happy to help you on this forum.

Comment: I managed to read the desired proprieties from the twin using DEVICE_TWIN_UPDATE_STATE  but the problem is that the process is very slow. It takes more than half a minute for the message to be received by the device. Am I doing something wrong or is this a disadvantage of the device twin method?

Comment: _more than half a minute for the message to be received by the device_ is something that needs to be investigated, this is not normal. Do you have Azure Monitor or any log\metrics which captured these long delays?

Comment: Also, See the [Operation throttles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#operation-throttles)

Comment: Another MSDN related question well answered by MVP-Roman Kiss, worth reading, [IOT HUB, C2D messages sent from Device Manager are very slow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/f772cc1f-18c9-4647-bef3-088820054286/iot-hub-c2d-messages-sent-from-device-manager-are-very-slow?forum=azureiothub)